# Parameterizing Routes in yii2

Tags: yii2, routes, url-routing

Was following this [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#parameterizing-routes) but not sure how to parameterize my routes in the following scenario

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        "login" => "site/login",
        "sign-up" => "site/sign-up",
        "search" => "site/search",
        "verify-email" => "site/verify-email",
    ],
],
```

These four rules basically have the same structure:
if accessing `Action` in the `Site` controller then the url will simply be `www.mydomain.com/<action>`

I tried creating a rule

`'<action:\w+>' => '<site:\w+>/<action:\w+>',`

...that didn't work so tried

`'<action:(login|sign-up|search|verify-email)>' => 'site/<action:(login|sign-up|search|verify-email)>',`

But only got 'page not found' (#404) error.

Would appreciate any suggestions. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'<action:(login|sign-up|search|verify-email)>' => 'site/<action>',
 ^                                                 ^
 |                                                 |
 pattern                                           route
```

Route SHOULD NOT contain any regexp patterns (like `<paramName:\w+>`), you may use `<paramName>` to insert param value to route, but you can not use any regexp in route.